# XML not opening in XML Editor

Tags: xml

Created XML not opening in browser and it throws error.

**My xml:**

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
 <newsitem>
<contentmeta>
<contentCreated>05/11/2014</contentCreated>
<contentModified>05/11/2014</contentModified>
 <classification1>*NULL*</classification1>
  <classification2>*NULL*</classification2>
  <geolocation1>*NULL*</geolocation1>
 <geolocation2>*NULL*</geolocation2>
<title>1</title>
 <headline>2</headline>
<subtitle>3</subtitle>
 <dateline>4</dateline>
  <bodytext>5 4 3 2 1<b><br>5 4 3 2</b><b><br>5 4 3</b><b><br>5 4</b><b><br>5</b> </bodytext>  ---> Error in this line
 <Keywords>*NULL*</Keywords>
 <pdfurl>BGL_2014_11_05_AM_01_MN.PDF</pdfurl>
</contentmeta>
</newsitem>
```

**Error:** 
The XML page cannot be displayed 
Cannot view XML input using XSL style sheet. Please correct the error and then click the Refresh button, or try again later.

---

End tag 'b' does not match the start tag 'br'. Error processing resource 'file:///C:/Documents and Settings/admin/My Docume...

5 4 3 2 1
**5 4 3 2**
**5 4 3**
5 4

Comment: close your `<br>` tag else it's **not a valid xml**. use `<br />`

Answer (score 2):

Your `bodytext` element looks like it is suppose to contain HTML, however you are entering it literally so it is being treated as XML.

XML is strict - every element must have a matching closing element, and be "balanced". In the case of your `<br>` elements, they have no matching closing element.

You have two options. You can either close the `<br>` element like `<br />`, or you can treat the `bodytext` as [CDATA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2784183/what-does-cdata-in-xml-mean), like so:

```
 <bodytext><![CDATA[ 5 4 3 2 1<b><br>5 4 3 2</b><b><br>5 4 3</b><b><br>5 4</b><b><br>5</b>  ]]></bodytext>
```

The latter might be more preferable, as the semantics behind XML and HTML aren't exactly the same (otherwise you are basically forcing yourself to write XHTML). This allows you to enter whatever you want and not have it treated as XML.

Answer (score 1):

Just like the message says: you close a `b` tag before closing the current `br` tag.  Remember, this is XML, not HTML; if you have a tag that does not have a closing tag (like `br`), you have to indicate it by using `<br/>`.  (Like @gp. said, but more succinctly.)

Answer (score 1):

The `br` tag is not closed!

Close it either as `<br/>` or as `<br> ... </br>`.